# Creating dynamic list view in jquery mobile not working?

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-mobile

When trying to create a dynamic listview on the fly i get this

[image: what i get]

here is my json

```
{"eventid":["61","23"],"name":["Clare Birthday","Mums Birthday"],"enddate":["Sat 27th April 2013","Wed 19th June 2013"]}
```

and here is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                                $(function(){
                                    var items="";
                                        $.getJSON("ajaxResponder.php?method=check-events",function(data){
                                            $("#contacts").html(
                                            '<li data-role="list-divider" role="heading">Live Events</li>'+
                                                $.each(data,function(index,item){
                                                    '<li><a href="check-events-details?eventid='+item.eventid+'" data-transition="slide">'+item.name+ 
                                                    '<p>End Date: '+item.enddate+'</p></li>'
                                                }));
                                            $("#contacts").listview("refresh");
                                        });
                                });

                        </script>

            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <ul id="contacts" data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="b" data-inset="true">
            </ul>
            </div>
```

can anyone see where i am going wrong?

Comment: I guess  `var items="";` should be `var items=[];`

Comment: thanks for your answer Omar but no luck.

Comment: You are not reading the array correctly. Try `item[index].eventid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you aren't reading the Array correctly. The below solution is bases on assumption that you want to create two list items with links to `id`. There are many ways to read arrays, it depends on how you want to output the data.

```
var object = {
 "eventid": ["61", "23"],
 "name": ["Clare Birthday", "Mums Birthday"],
 "enddate": ["Sat 27th April 2013", "Wed 19th June 2013"]
};
```

First, you need to convert JSON object to an Array.

```
var array = [object];
```

And then loop inside it. I used `for` statement here to loop twice.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
 $.each(array, function (index, values) {
  var events = values.eventid;
  var names = values.name;
  var enddates = values.enddate;
  $('[data-role="listview"]').append('<li><a href=link"' + events[i] + '"> ' + names[i] + ' - ' + enddates[i] + '</a></li>');
  $('[data-role="listview"]').listview('refresh');
 });
}
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/jyb8J/)**

***Note:** Element `id` should start with a letter not a number.*